# C# Common DbContext for ASP.NET Identity with webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, asp.net-identity

I'm beginner to .NET but I'm fairly familiar with building webapplications using 3 tier architecture. I usually have a webapplication project for the webforms and a wpf application project to keep my Domain, Controller and Data Access Layer classes.

I'm familiar with creating a DbContext class and using it to deal with the database through EF. I've added .NET Identity to my webapplication project but I need to make changes to the identity user and add more data to it.

I'm following [this](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/asp-net-identity-tutorial-user-login-and-registration/) tutorial to accomplish this but it is intended for MVC. I have 2 seperate context files at the moment, one for identity and other for my usual purposes. is there a way I can have one context?

my DbContext looks like,

```
    namespace ExammerCore.Infrastructure
{
    class ExammerContext : DbContext
    {
        public ExammerContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

the identity DbContext I made using the tutorial looks like,

```
namespace ExammerCore.Infrastructure
{
    class IdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public IdentityContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

My IdentityModels.cs looks like,

```
namespace ExammerCore.Domain
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {

        //You can extend this class by adding additional fields like Birthday
        public string BirthDate { get; set; }

    }

}
```

how can I blend these two together to have one DbContext class? or is there another way to add custom fields to a user without inheriting Identity classes?
My solution structure looks like this,
[Solution structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYN14.png)

I've googled a lot haven't found an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line

```
class ExammerContext : DbContext
```

to

```
class ExammerContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

to pull all the Identity DbSets into your ExammerContext

Comment: Is that all I have to do? I will be able to manage the rest of my model through this context as well after that?

Comment: Yes, you don't need the separate IdentityContext.  You'll be left with just your updated ExammerContext.

Answer (score 0):

in your dbcontext you should have properties that represent what entities get used to build tables.... that should look something like this...

```
class ExammerContext : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    // add other classes/tables here.

    public ExammerContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }
}
```

this way you will only need your context.